# Why does MapViewOfFile fail with ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED?

Tags: c, winapi, shared-memory

I came across this situation with WinAPI's [`MapViewOfFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366761%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function. An Internet search didn't turn up any apparent fixes, so I will share my problem and solution here.

Consider the following snippet:

```
const char *name = "Global\\Object_Name";
unsigned long size = get_object_size();

HANDLE handle = CreateFileMapping(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE,
                                  NULL,
                                  PAGE_READWRITE,
                                  0,
                                  size,
                                  name);

if (!handle || handle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    exit(GetLastError());

bool created = GetLastError() == 0;

void *block = MapViewOfFile( handle,
                             FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS,
                             0,
                             0,
                             size);

if (block == NULL)
    exit(GetLastError());
```

In one particular case, `CreateFileMapping` was successfully returning a handle. `GetLastError` was returning `ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS`, so `created == false`. Now, the call to `MapViewOfFile`, using the same size that I passed to `CreateFileMapping`, returns `NULL` and `GetLastError` returns `0x05`: `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`. The process was running with administrator privileges.

The MSDN documentation doesn't really mention any reason why this situation would occur. So why does `CreateFileMapping` succeed, but `MapViewOfFile` fail?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm sure there are many reasons why `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` could occur from a call to `MapViewOfFile`. In my particular situation, it was due to the `size` argument.

The hint is in the fact that `created == false`. It shows that the object `"Global\\Object_Name"` has already been created. For whatever reason, the creating call initialised the section with a smaller size. For what seems like an oversight, the second call to `CreateFileMapping` will happily give you a handle to the already-existing object, even if you asked for a bigger mapping.

The call to `MapViewOfFile` now fails, because it's requesting a view that is bigger than the actual section.

So, if you're in a similar situation where the second call to `MapViewOfFile` fails, check the size that you're trying to map to.

It could be that the second project is compiling with a different structure alignment, resulting in the `sizeof()` operator determining different values, or some other size-determining function is not behaving as expected.

Answer (score 10):

After a lot of suffer, I finally found what was causing this error in my application, in case someone else is struggling with the same, the problem is not with the MapViewOfFile method, but with the CreateFileMapping, the size of the createFileMapping should be the size of the file, not the size of the  element to read, if you don't know the size then it should be 0, this does not apply to the MapViewOfFile as the value to pass as size is the length of the block you want to read/write.

Your code working will look like this:

```
const char *name = "Global\\Object_Name";
unsigned long size = get_object_size();

HANDLE handle = CreateFileMapping(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE,
                                  NULL,
                                  PAGE_READWRITE,
                                  0,
                                  0,
                                  name);

if (!handle || handle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    exit(GetLastError());

bool created = GetLastError() == 0;

void *block = MapViewOfFile( handle,
                             FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS,
                             0,
                             0,
                             size);

if (block == NULL)
    exit(GetLastError());
```

A just putting this here to document what I found, unfortunately is hard to search for this error when you don't know what is causing it. I hope this saves a couple of hours to someone else.